# SVGs and height

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass

I have an SVG I'd like to use as a background image. I want the width to be 100% but when I expand the screen size the height follows and increases along with the width.

The most important part of the image for me is the bottom center but when the screen is too large there is a ton scrolling required to get there.

I'm trying to place the focus on the bottom center and when it expands to have the height expand above and have it hidden behind overflow: hidden.

I can't seem to get it to work. Is it possible to get this image to stay in place height-wise and let it expand but stay focused on the bottom center of the SVG?

Also I should note, I'm just aware that the overflow hidden is probably in the wrong place, I just put it there to see if anything would happen because it didn't work in the #hero

Thanks in advance.

react component

```
import bground from '../images/background.svg';

const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <div id="hero">
      Hello
      <div>
        hello
        <img
          id="background-img"
          width={`100%`}
          height={`100%`}
          src={bground}
          alt="background"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

scss file

```scss
#hero {
  position: relative;
  height: 85vh;
  width: 100vw;

  #background-img {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: This type of question would be much easier to work through with just HTML and CSS. You can then translate the solution to your React app later.

Comment: Note that in your question, not down here. :)